# Google App Engine - custom URL for web clients, endpoints for mobile clients?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm developing an Android app and am using Google App Engine as the back-end. I want to use Endpoints since it seems easy to set up and appears to make authentication easy, but I've seen that it doesn't support custom domains. I'd like to use a custom domain to allow users to log-in and make changes with a web client, though not through Endpoints.

What I want to know is what they mean when they say that custom domains aren't supported. Does that mean you can't use Endpoints at all in your project if you've set up a custom domain for it, or that you just can't make Endpoints API calls to a custom domain?

If it's the latter, I've written a utility class that both my Endpoints API class and servlets could call, so my web client doesn't need to interact with Endpoints at all, only the mobile clients do. I'd like Endpoints and the servlets to be part of the same project so they can both access the same data in the Datastore.

If anyone knows whether this is possible or if there's a better way of going about this, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out and found that it is possible to use Endpoints in a GAE project that uses a custom domain, so long as the custom domain is not used to call the Endpoints API. So when it says in the Endpoints documentation that custom domains are not supported, it simply means you can't make API calls to a custom domain, as I suspected.